# import strings into scrapy to use as crawl urls

Tags: python

So my question is how do I tell scrapy to crawl URLs, which only set apart by one string. So for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=STRING
I got the strings saved in a txt file.

```
with open("plz_nummer.txt") as f:
    cityZIP = f.read().rsplit('\n') 

for a in xrange(0,len(cityZIP)):

    next_url = 'http://www.firmenfinden.de/?txtPLZ=' + cityZIP[a] + '&txtBranche=&txtKunden='
        pass
```

Comment: Do you really mean to say you want to append 2 strings? Can you share some code?

Comment: So i did nothing special yet, but I dont know how to tell scrapy to crawl these links

Comment: Can you also paste an excerpt from your `plz_nummer.txt` file? And why did you add the `scrapy` tag? Are you using the `scrapy` framework?

Comment: yes, and in the plz_nummer.txt are just 5 digit numbers (zip-codes)

Comment: Please paste your scrapy code for this question.

Comment: there is no scrapy code yet because i need to figure out how to set the crawl URL to the variable next_url (created in the code i shared) first

Comment: Got it. Can you tell me what do you see when you print `next_url` right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make the loading of the file with zip codes part of the `start_requests` method as a generator. Something in the lines of:

```
import scrapy

class ZipSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "zipCodes"
    self.city_zip_list = []

    def start_requests(self):
        with open("plz_nummer.txt") as f:
            self.city_zip_list = f.read().rsplit('\n')
        for city_zip in self.city_zip_list:
            url = 'http://www.firmenfinden.de/?txtPLZ={}&txtBranche=&txtKunden='.format(city_zip)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)  

    def parse(self, response):
        # Anything else you need
        # to do in here
        pass
```

This should give you a good starting point. Also read this article: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.1/intro/tutorial.html